# How to fully reset/clear ASP.NET Core MVC form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to use JS (or jQuery) to reset a form. It works fine if fill out the fields and click Reset. The problem starts when I submit the form with at least one field having a model error. When the form with model errors is returned back and I click reset, the fields that did not have model errors do not reset.

What is happening here and how can I make all fields always reset, regardless of whether or not there were any model errors? Additionally, I would like to have the model errors disappear on reset too.

Gif below shows the field I highlight does not reset:

[image: I want highlighted field to reset]

HTML

```
@model SampleViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


<script>
    function ResetFormWithJS() {
        document.getElementById('FormEyeDee').reset();
    }
</script>

<center>
    <form id="FormEyeDee"asp-action="Index" method="post">
        Name:
        <input asp-for="Name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        <hr />
        Email:
        <input asp-for="Email" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        <hr />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" onclick="ResetFormWithJS();" />
    </form>
    <br>
</center>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(SampleViewModel Model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index", Model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is happening here and how can I make all fields always reset, regardless of whether or not there were any model errors? Additionally, I would like to have the model errors disappear on reset too.

To achieve the requirement, you can try to reference `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` to support client-side validation, which would also help avoid an unnecessary round trip to the server.

```
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: I should have made my test case more accurate to the app I'm working on because I don't actually use data annotations on my model properties. I make a call to the server to validate the form because there is extra complexity to it, so I don't think _ValidationScriptsPartial would help in my app. But seeing your answer answers the question I posted, I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a pure JavaScript solution, try this:

```js
function ResetFormWithJS() {
    document.querySelector("[asp-for='Name']").value = "";
    document.querySelector("[asp-for='Email']").value = "";
}
```

Or with JQuery:

```js
function ResetFormWithJS() {
    $("[asp-for='Name']").val("");
    $("[asp-for='Email']").val("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this wouldn't actually work because in ASP.NET Core `asp-for` is a tag helper that renders the tag's attributes in the DOM. So, when the page loads the `asp-for` tag is gone. However, one of the tags it renders is `name` that `asp-for` can be replaced with in your code.